# Delete File using JList

Tags: java, file, jlist

I want to delete file using JList. Here is my code:

```
        ListModel model = matchedFilesList.getModel();

        int i = matchedFilesList.getSelectedIndex();
        File delFile = new File(model.getElementAt(i).toString());
        System.out.println(delFile.getName().substring(4));
        delFile=new File(delFile.getName().substring(4));
        try{
        if (delFile.delete()) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, delFile.getName() + " Deleted successfully");
        } 
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

It is not getting deleted. Gives error. No error messages at all.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: the file will probably need to be pathed

Comment: delFile.delete remains false.

Comment: What's error message?

Comment: Does the file actually exist? Try printing out delFile.exist()

Comment: File exists but it is not getting picked up. I tried .exists. it gives false as well. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ListModel` try to use [`DefaultListModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html). after that use `remove()` method. Here is a complete example - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/ListDemoProject/src/components/ListDemo.java

Here from the `GUI` clicking the fire button delete a user from the list. Please investigate the code and you will understand by yourself.

Hope it will help.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: While good advice, *"It is not getting deleted. Gives error."* doesn't answer the problem...

Comment: Sir I am trying to delete a file from the system as well.